# Create recursive topology tree with Python

Tags: python, list, recursion, tree, topology

I have a df1 with two columns representing links:

```
point_1 point_2
  'A'     'B'
  'B'     'C'
  'C'     'D'
  'D'     'E'
  'D'     'F'
  'M'     'N'
  'N'     'O'
...
```

And I have another df2 with point_A and end_point (that is a point where three need to break for that point) and some point_A can have more than one end_point.

```
    point_A  end_point
      'A'        'E'
      'A'        'F'
      'M'        'O'
...
```

I wasn't really sure how to implement that and I using some function and the way below:
First I convert df1 to list:

```
temp = []
for row in df1.iterrows():
    index, data = row
    temp.append(data.tolist())

final_list = [[s.encode('ascii') for s in list] for list in temp]
```

Now the function:

```
def all_paths(table, root):
    children = {}
    for node, child in table:
        if child: 
            children[node] = children.setdefault(node, []) + [child]

    def recurse(path):
        yield path
        if path[-1] in children:
            for child in children[path[-1]]:
                for foo in recurse(path + [child]):
                    yield foo

    return recurse([root])

path_list = []
for el in d:
    for i in el:
        for path in all_paths(final_list, i):
            path_list.append(path)
```

And I got this:
path_list:

```
[['A'],
 ['A', 'B'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F']
 ['M'],
 ['M', 'N'],
 ['M', 'N', 'O']
...
]
```

As you can see I got a lot of list items and I don't need them, I need just the items with all point from point_A to end_point. So, my idea was now to compare the first element of each item in the list with point_A and list element in the same item in the list with the end_point. If it's equal that mean it's correct.

Desired output:

```
[
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F']
 ['M', 'N', 'O']
...
]
```

I would be better in dataframe, but this is ok too.

But I'm sure there is much easier and more correct solution.
Any help is welcomed.

Comment: So what you need to do is: for each start point, get a set of the end points. And then when you produce a path, you check if its end point is in that set, if so it is reported.

Comment: @DanD. Well, I think that we think the same, but to be sure: I need for each start point all points from start until the end point. List of that points will represent the path. There is just one end point for each start point, but in my dataset it's left_side-right_side links form. Maybe that's what is confusing

Answer (score 1):

```
point_A  end_point
  'A'        'E'
  'A'        'F'
  'M'        'O'
```

The idea is that you take this table and create:

```
points = {'A':set(['E','F']), 'M':set(['O'])}
```

then you loop over this:

```
for start_point, end_points in points.items():
    for path in all_paths(final_list, start_point, end_points):
```

Then in the `all_paths` function:

replace

```
yield path
```

with:

```
if path[-1] in end_points:
   yield path
```

This test results in any path that does not end at one of the given points to not be reported.

You may be able to speed this up by finding the connected components of the  links and then ensuring that only the pairs that have both their start and end points in the same component have their paths enumerated.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. In df1 you can see that A is connected with E and F over B, C and D. So in output I need all of them. Actually, for A I need two output sets, one with B, C, D and E, and the other one with B, C, D, F. df2 is just for checking if the end is ok.